# Symfony2 : How to render an HTML5 number input type and accept float values in a form?

Tags: html, forms, symfony, input, numbers

I want to use symfony integer field type because it uses HTML5 "number" input type which is more appropriated for numbers.

When I create my form inside of my controller:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($stuff)
 ->add('freqLivrLO', 'integer', array(
            'label' => 'Fréquence de livraison (nb fois/semaine)',
            'rounding_mode'=>null,
            'precision'=>2,
            'constraints' => array(
                new GreaterThan(array(
                    'value' => 0, 'message' => 'La fréquence de livraison doit être strictement positive')),
                new LessThanOrEqual(array(
                    'value' => 7, 'message' => 'La fréquence de livraison doit être inférieure à 7'))
            ),
            'attr' => array('step'=>'0.01',
                'min'=>'0',
                'max'=>'7'),
        ))
```

It renders properly a number field:

```
<input id="form_freqLivrLO" name="form[freqLivrLO]" required="required" step="0.01" min="0" max="7" value="0.07" type="number">
```

However, whenever I enter a float value, it's rounded to the next available integer. What should I do ?

Answer (score 6):

Taking cues from Adambean, you can do:

```
->add('lat', NumberType::class, array (
    'required' => true,
    'scale' => 7,
    'attr' => array(
       'min' => -90,
       'max' => 90,
       'step' => 0.0000001,
    ),
))
```

In your Twig template, you will need to define the type, and in my case, it looks like:

```
{{ form_widget(edit_form.lat, { 'type':'number' }) }}
```

Comment: It's working fine for my Symfony 2.8.9, best answer imho.

Comment: This is better than my cheeky JQuery solution. Definitely use this.

Answer (score 4):

For the moment, the only workaround I could find is to create a custom form field type that unherits number. Instead of displaying it as a text input, I display it as a number input.

Sources :

1. http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html
2. http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#cookbook-form-customization-form-themes

**Step 1 : Creating the custom form field**

In your bundle repository, create your custom form class (be careful on the namespace) ***FloatType.php***

```
<?php
namespace <Base Bundle Name>\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class FloatType extends AbstractType
{

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'number';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'float';
    }
}
```

As you can see your new type simply unherit from number type. We will use it later to call the proper rendering of your form field.

**Step 2 : Creating the template.**

To render properly your newly created form type, you need to call a form template. As your new type unherit from number, it will greatly simplify the task.

In the Ressource repository of your bundle, create inside of the view repository a repository called Form. Inside this repository, we are going to create the Twig template ***float.html.twig*** that will be used to render your custom field :

```
{% block float_widget %}
    {% set type = type|default('number') %}
    {{ block('form_widget_simple') }}
{% endblock float_widget %}
```

**Step 3 : Link and use**

At last, the only thing remaining is to add your template as a twig ressource in ***app/config/config.yml***

```
# Twig Configuration
twig:
    #use a custom field type for float values
    form:
        resources:
            - '<Bundle full name>:Form:float.html.twig'
```

And to use it in your controller :

```
use <Base Bundle>\Form\Type\FloatType;
...

$form = $this->createFormBuilder($stuff)
->add('freqLivrLO', new FloatType(), array(
            'label' => 'Fréquence de livraison (nb fois/semaine)',
            'precision'=>2,
            'constraints' => array(
                new GreaterThan(array(
                    'value' => 0, 'message' => 'La fréquence de livraison doit être strictement positive')),
                new LessThanOrEqual(array(
                    'value' => 7, 'message' => 'La fréquence de livraison doit être inférieure à 7'))
            ),
            'attr' => array('step'=>'0.01',
                'min'=>'0',
                'max'=>'7'),
        ))
```

And that's it ! Any better solution will be greatly appreciated :D

Answer (score 2):

I got around this by using a bit of cheeky JQuery to change the input type at runtime.

Here is my entry in the form type:

```
->add('totalDays', 'number', array(
    'required'      => false,
    'scale'         => 1,
    'attr'          => array(
        '_type'         => "number",
        'min'           => 0,
        'step'          => 0.5,
    ),
))
```

Now here's my JQuery to change the input type to what was defined in the "_type" attribute:

```
$('input').each(function(k, v){
    if ($(this).attr('_type')) {
        $(this).prop('type', $(this).attr('_type'));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `number` form type instead of `integer`. And all will work fine! just change

```
 ->add('freqLivrLO', 'integer', array(...
```

To

```
 ->add('freqLivrLO', 'number', array(...
```

Comment: When you use this, the value is automatically rounded to the nearest integer by Symfony2 when it's stored in the object, and this is not what I want

Comment: Are you storing the form value in a database? If so, what is the column type?